# Acceder a la propiedad bitmap de un componente hijo desde el padre

Tags: delphi

En tiempo de ejecución se crean varios `TSpeedButton` y dentro de los mismos un solo componente hijo `TImage` y tengo asignado para los `TSpeedButton` un evento `onClick`

```
  Square := TSpeedButton.Create(Self);
  Square.Parent := rec_GenerationArea;
  Square.Name := BN + COLORS[x] + SHAPES[y];
  Square.Text := EmptyStr;

  SquareIMG := TImage.Create(Self);
  SquareIMG.Parent := Square;

  Square.OnClick := BNClick;
```

Lo que yo quiero hacer es que al momento de hacer click en esos botones creados se coloque una imagen. ¿Pero cómo puedo acceder a las propiedades de un componente hijo (TImage) desde su Padre (TSpeedButton) ?

Aclaro que estoy desde Firemonkey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El *problema* que enfrentas puede dividirse en dos partes, y para responder a ellas vamos a ver primero algo de teoría:

### Como acceder a los hijos de un control: `Controls`

Todos los controles (aquellos objetos que derivan de `TControl`) tienen una propiedad llamada `Controls`, que es una lista de sus controles hijos. Controles, en este caso, significa que también heredan de `TControl`. Podemos acceder a los elementos individuales de esta lista por su índice, como si se tratase de un arreglo, por ejemplo, puedo acceder al sexto hijo de `MiControl` con la sintaxis: `MiControl.Controls[5]`.

### Como acceder a una propiedad en particular de un hijo particular: Moldes de tipo

El siguiente inconveniente es que la propiedad Controls devuelve instancias de `TControl`, y tu quieres acceder a la propiedad `Bitmap`, que está declarada más abajo en la jerarquía.

Podemos valernos de los operadores `is` y `as` para verificar y aplicar moldes de tipo seguros, además del nombre de la clase utilizado como función, que aplica un molde de tipo incondicional.

Esto también es necesario para acceder a la propiedad `Controls` del botón, dado que la firma del evento es `OnClick(Sender: TObject)`.

Los operadores se utilizan así:

- `is`: El operador `is` evalúa si la instancia de objeto `es` de la clase dada y devuelve `True` o `False`. Por ejemplo: `Gato is TAnimal` debiera devolver `True` mientras que `Gato is TPersona` devuera devolver `False`. Acá el verbo *es*, significa que el objeto es directamente una instancia de la clase, o que su clase hereda de la clase dada. Así, `Gato is TMamifero`, `Gato is TFelino` y `Gato is TGato` devolverían todas `True`.
- `as`: Aplica un molde seguro de tipo. Es decir, hace una conversión de tipo, solo si el objeto dado `es` de la clase dada. Devuelve una referencia al objeto, al nivel de la clase dada en jerarquía. Si el objeto no *es* de la clase dada, eleva una excepción. Veamos con un ejemplo, todas las asignaciones siguientes serían exitosas:

  ```
    var
      Objeto: TObject;
      Animal: TAnimal;
      Gato: TGato;
    begin
      Objeto := TGato.Create;
      Animal := Objeto as TGato; 
      Animal := Objeto as TAnimal;
      Gato := Objeto as TGato;
      Gato := Animal as TGato;
    end;
  ```

  Recordar que las referencias a objetos son asignables a variables de su mismo tipo o de cualquiera de sus ancestros. En este caso, `Objeto as TGato` devuelve una referencia a `TGato`, pero dado que `TGato` hereda de `TAnimal`, la asignación es posible. Por esta misma regla es que podemos asignar directamente el resultado de `TGato.Create` a una variable de tipo `TObject`.

  En cambio la siguiente asignación no tendría efecto y se elevará una excepción:

  ```
    var
      Objeto: TObject;
      Gato: TGato;
    begin
      Objeto := TPersona.Create;
      Gato := Objeto as TGato;
    end;
  ```
- Molde de tipo incondicional. Acá, le estamos diciendo al compilador que sabemos lo que hacemos y lo queremos hacer sin validación alguna. Para ello, utilizamos el Tipo como si se tratase de una función, por ejemplo:

  ```
    var
      Objeto: TObject;
      Animal: TAnimal;
    begin
      Objeto := TGato.Create;
      Animal := TAnimal(Objeto); 
    end;
  ```

  TAnimal(Objeto) nos va a devolver una referencia de tipo `TAnimal`, sin importar que hay en Objeto. Debemos ser cuidadosos, pues facilmente podemos provocar errores y comportamientos indefinidos en un programa si aplicamos un molde de tipo incorrecto, sin embargo hay casos donde podemos jugar a la segura, por ejemplo evitando una doble verificación de tipo en una asignación que siga el patrón:

  ```
    if Objeto is TGato then
      Gato := TGato(Objeto);
  ```

  En este caso, el código resultante será más óptimo (menos de un nanosegundo más veloz, en dispositivos modernos), pues no hace una segunda validación forzada por el operador `as`.

### Entonces, ¿cómo luce la solución?

Poniendo las piezas juntas, en el manejador de evento `BNClick` que referencias en el código, podrías tener algo como:

```
procedure TMiFormulario.BNClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Imagen: TImage;
  Control: TControl;
begin
  Imagen := nil;
  for Control in (Sender as TControl).Controls do
    if Control is TImage then
    begin
      Imagen := TImage(Control);
      break;
    end;
  if Assigned(Imagen) then
    Imagen.Bitmap.LoadFromFile('MiImagen.png');
end;
```

Notarás que recorro la lista de controles. Esto es por robustez, en su implementación actual el `TSpeedButton` tiene un `TLayout` como primer hijo, por lo que podría asumir que el botón está siempre en la segunda posición, pero eso en un futuro podría cambiar, además de que podría cambiar también en mi propio código. Si, a pesar de la advertencia prefieres ese enfoque, puedes hacerlo sin recorrer la lista, por ejemplo:

```
procedure TMiFormulario.BNClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Imagen: TImage;
begin
  Imagen := (Sender as TControl).Controls[1] as TImage;
  Imagen.Bitmap.LoadFromFile('MiImagen.png');
end;
```